# Run ARM coprocessor instructions with sudo

Tags: c++, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, inline-assembly

My goal is to write to the coprocessor p15 register, and right now I'm just trying to read it.

I have the following example c++ program, the first asm instruction is just a simple ror, which works just fine. The second asm instruction, I'm trying to just read SCTLR register.

I compile the program with g++ test_program.cpp -o test
and run with ./test or sudo ./test

If I run with ./test, I get the output:

```
Value: 10   Result: 8
Illegal instruction
```

If I run with sudo ./test, I get:

```
Value: 10   Result: 8
```

So clearly the instruction is not working since its not printing the line "got here" or "SCTLR". Is there something else I have to do to execute the coprocessor read? I'm running this on a raspberry pi (Cortex A-53).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
unsigned int y, x;
x = 16;

//Assembly rotate right 1 example
asm("mov    %[result], %[value], ror #1"

           : [result]"=r" (y) /* Rotation result. */
           : [value]"r"   (x) /* Rotated value. */
           : /* No clobbers */
    );

printf("Value: %x   Result: %x\n", x, y);


// Assembly read SCTLR, program crashes if this is run
unsigned int id = 0;
asm("MRC    p15, 0, %[result], c0, c0, 0"
           : [result]"=r" (id)  //Rotation result.
    );

printf("Got here\n");

printf("SCTLR: %x", id);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not SCTLR, it's MIDR. Anyway, have a closer look at which CP15 registers are accessible _from user mode_; it's very few of them.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to access them from privileged mode, I was hoping I could use sudo to give myself permission

Comment: Processes running as root still run in user mode. You need kernel code (eg. a driver) to do anything privileged mode.

Comment: Okay I see, is there any resource you can recommend for creating a program that can run in privileged mode?

Comment: Search for 'linux kernel modules'.